# Native crash at /system/lib/libhwui.so

Tags: android

I keep getting numerous crash reports via google play store. All crashes occur on Samsung Galaxy S4 running on Android Version 4.4.

I do not work with the Android NDK.

According to one user the app crashes when you take a picture. Currently I have no S4 to reproduce the problem.

I have tested the App via [Samsungs RemoteTestLab](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action) on a S4 with Andorid 4.4 but all seems to work fine.

Is there a way to contact Samsung developer?

All reports look similar:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/jfltexx/jflte:4.4.2/KOT49H/I9505XXUFNB8:user/release-keys'
Revision: '11'
pid: 21062, tid: 21062, name: ktwas.appjobber >>> de.werdenktwas.appjobber <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 3f800010
r0 bee2bf4c r1 00000000 r2 00000001 r3 00000000
r4 3f800000 r5 79391398 r6 00000000 r7 795de140
r8 00000000 r9 40ee8274 sl bee2c380 fp bee2c31c
ip 00000001 sp bee2bf40 lr 40eda315 pc 40eda322 cpsr 200f0030
d0 3f80000033d6bf95 d1 0000000000000000
d2 3f80000000000000 d3 33d6bf953f800000
d4 0000000000000000 d5 3f80000000000000
d6 3f80000000000000 d7 0000000000000000
d8 448e800043870000 d9 445980004428c000
d10 0000000043ca8000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 0000000000000000 d17 2820657275747865
d18 0000000000000000 d19 0000000000000000
d20 0000000000000000 d21 0000000000000000
d22 3f80000000000000 d23 00000000bf800000
d24 bf29ef9c59f8249e d25 bfdb0c2dc0e71a39
d26 3fd7e1cb6ac20e40 d27 bf56ad0de153a4f7
d28 4012d97c7f3321d2 d29 3fdbecdeaeef4ba0
d30 3fc1d2cda3115147 d31 40000e9980000000
scr 28000012

backtrace:
#00 pc 0002b322 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#01 pc 0001f329 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#02 pc 00020525 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#03 pc 000207b7 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#04 pc 00021d03 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#05 pc 00017bb7 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#06 pc 00015463 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#07 pc 00015357 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#08 pc 0001e08b /system/lib/libhwui.so
#09 pc 0006c299 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#10 pc 00020bcc /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#11 pc 00051927 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#12 pc 0002a060 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#13 pc 00031510 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#14 pc 0002eba8 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#15 pc 00064159 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
#16 pc 0006c18f /system/lib/libdvm.so
#17 pc 0002a060 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#18 pc 00031510 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#19 pc 0002eba8 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#20 pc 00063e75 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#21 pc 0004d457 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#22 pc 00051f0f /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#23 pc 000534a3 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
#24 pc 0000105b /system/bin/app_process
#25 pc 0000e4f3 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
#26 pc 00000d7c /system/bin/app_process

code around pc:
40eda300 8000f8d3 0201f108 f7e5601a 4641f9cf
40eda310 fb08f7e7 40acf8d5 60acf8c5 d04f2c00
40eda320 edd4a803 ed947a04 eef80a05 eeb88a67
40eda330 f7f18a40 4628f81d 464aa903 fd44f7ff
40eda340 f8d54628 462120b0 30b4f8d5 fd28f7ff
40eda350 f6406820 910151e1 6101f242 460a4633
40eda360 68c59600 47a84620 46384918 f7fd4479
40eda370 4641fc5c ea1cf7e2 46384915 f7fd4479
40eda380 ab03fc54 21014632 eb62f7e2 46384911
40eda390 f7fd4479 eef7fc4a eec00a00 ee808aa8
40eda3a0 ee181a88 ee111a90 f7e22a10 7e23ed3e
40eda3b0 4620b133 fbd8f000 46206822 47886851
40eda3c0 ecbdb015 e8bd8b02 bf0083f0 00009576
40eda3d0 00009574 00009571 ed2db5f8 46048b02
40eda3e0 8a1eed9f ed802500 60058a06 8a07ed80
40eda3f0 ed806045 60858a08 8a09ed80 f10460c5

code around lr:
40eda2f4 4691b095 9b1e4605 2600460f 8000f8d3
40eda304 0201f108 f7e5601a 4641f9cf fb08f7e7
40eda314 40acf8d5 60acf8c5 d04f2c00 edd4a803
40eda324 ed947a04 eef80a05 eeb88a67 f7f18a40
40eda334 4628f81d 464aa903 fd44f7ff f8d54628
40eda344 462120b0 30b4f8d5 fd28f7ff f6406820
40eda354 910151e1 6101f242 460a4633 68c59600
40eda364 47a84620 46384918 f7fd4479 4641fc5c
40eda374 ea1cf7e2 46384915 f7fd4479 ab03fc54
40eda384 21014632 eb62f7e2 46384911 f7fd4479
40eda394 eef7fc4a eec00a00 ee808aa8 ee181a88
40eda3a4 ee111a90 f7e22a10 7e23ed3e 4620b133
40eda3b4 fbd8f000 46206822 47886851 ecbdb015
40eda3c4 e8bd8b02 bf0083f0 00009576 00009574
40eda3d4 00009571 ed2db5f8 46048b02 8a1eed9f
40eda3e4 ed802500 60058a06 8a07ed80 ed806045
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution in Android [Issue 67282](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67282) report, please check the solution in [#11](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67282#c11).

Use software acceleration can fix this issue. You can try it.

```
mTextView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); // WORKS on API Level 19 (OpenGL ES 3.0)
```